Как прочитать переменную из css в JS
Всем добрый день.
У меня есть глобальная переменная с .css
Пытаюсь прочитать ее в файле, в консоли пишет %22download_file.html?file_id=745%22
Кто сталкивался с подобной задачей, подскажите как ее решали?


const currentRoot = document.querySelector(':root');
const currentStyle = getComputedStyle(currentRoot);
const fetchIconCross = currentStyle.getPropertyValue('--iconCross');
console.log(fetchIconCross);
$('#test').attr('crs', fetchIconCross);
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style>
  --iconCross: "download_file.html?file_id=745";
</style>
<div>
  <img id="test" src="download_file.html?file_id=745">
</div>



Решил таким способом
--iconCross: download_file.html?file_id=745;

Переменные в CSS не могут существовать сами по себе. Они должны где-то находится, а для этого их можно занести скажем в селектор :root, то-есть как-то так: :root { --iconCross: "какое-то значени"; }
